# Non-nullable instance field 'questionAnswer' must be initialized. (Documentation), Non-nullable instance field 'questionText' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbBER.jpg)

I find this code working on previous version of flutter but it's not working on my new updated version. Can Anyone have a solution for this problem? Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor like:

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required this.questionText, required this.questionAnswer});
}
```

or go with:

```
class Question {
  late String questionName;
  late bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required String q,required bool a}){
    questionName = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

The constructor cant have null value and should pass something to it

Answer (score 0):

Replace your string `String questionText;` to `String questionText = "";`

```
class Question {
  String questionText = "";
  bool questionAnswer = "";

  Question({required this.questionText, required this.questionAnswer});
}
```